# Should both of the opencv matrices produce the same transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coordinate-systems, transformation

Shouldnt $\begin{bmatrix}
  x \\
  y \\
  z \\
\end{bmatrix}
$ from both equations be the same?

eq(1)$\begin{bmatrix}
  x \\
  y \\
  z \\
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} \\r_{21} & r_{22} & r_{23} \\r_{31} & r_{32} & r_{33} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
  X \\
  Y \\
  Z \\
\end{bmatrix} + tvec
$

eq(2)$
 \begin{bmatrix}
  x \\
  y \\
  z \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} & t_x\\r_{21} & r_{22} & r_{23} & t_y\\r_{31} & r_{32} & r_{33} & t_x\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
  X \\
  Y \\
  Z \\
  1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: you have forgot a $1$ in equation 2.

Comment: The multiplication in your second equation is not defined. You cannot multiply a $3 \times 4$ matrix with a $3 \times 1$ matrix.

Comment: You(both) are correct. Changing the input point on the right to include 1 stopped my run-time error and both are "working" in the code but different results.

Comment: correcting the errors above set the stage for isolating the problem further. I inadvertently recycled the first rotational matrix resulting in 2 different transformation matrices in eq.1 and eq.2 that being the reason they were not equal. Once fixed, output from both eq.1/eq.2 were the same.

Comment: Are you now ready to delete your question?

Comment: Obviously I am a new poster. If I remove the question on what grounds? The first two respondents flagged that the input coordinate [X Y Z] was missing a homogeneous coordinate 1, which unraveled the yarn. Their knowledge was important to resolve the issue.

Comment: [X Y Z] -> [X Y Z 1]